# I need help reading analog voltages in an arduino mega2560

Tags: arduino

I'm new to microcontrollers and I need help reading voltages and printing them in the serial monitor. I have done this using a potentiometer, but I was wondering if I could do the same with just voltages. Below is the code that I used when I read the potentiometer values:

I have tried reading voltages but when I input a voltage smaller than between 3-5V in pin A0 I get 0s in the serial monitor

```
int potPin = 0;    // select the input pin
int val = 0;       // variable to store the value coming from the function generator
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);   // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}
void loop() {
  val = analogRead(potPin); // read the value from the function generator
  Serial.println(val);
  delay(1000); //Sampling rate for the signal
}
```

Comment: Since your code is simple enough the issue is most probably on the hardware side. Maybe you forgot to connect ground properly? Without a circuit diagram it is almost impossible to guess what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

as Udo Klein said, this looks like a hardware issue. try setting up your circuit like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s5Gs.jpg

note that the grounds are shared between the function generator and the arduino - this is important for ensuring that voltages are measured correctly. remember that voltage is actually a *difference* in electric potential, so you need a common reference point to measure from.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes you can read voltages from another piece of hardware.

As gearbot tells you it is important to keep a common ground between the arduino and the other piece of hardware.

Also be carefull, the arduino can only measure voltages between 0 and 5 Volts. Don't try to measure higher voltages without adjusting the circuitry as you might destroy your arduino board.

If you're unsure measure the voltages before attaching to the arduino with a multimeter.

The Uno has 6 analog inputs, labeled A0 through A5, each of which provide 10 bits of resolution (i.e. 1024 different values). By default they measure from ground to 5 volts, though is it possible to change the upper end of their range using the AREF pin and the analogReference() function.

edit:

I didn't see the added comment at the bottom of your post. This indicates indeed a hardware problem (probably in your circuitry)

To be sure the arduino does the right thing, measure the voltage with your multimeter between pin A0 and GND while your hardware is attached and working. You should be able to read the correct voltage there.

I suspect it will give the same values as the Arduino.
Then trace back your circuitry with your multimeter (keeping GND attached) to find where something is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try scaling your 0 to 5 or 1-5v input
using map function.

int setValue = map(ana1Value, 0, 1023, 0, 100);

could be a help for you.

the analogue input voltage is the scaled 0-100 then you can work with that